# How many levels of inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, frameworks

Are there any best practices regarding the maximum depth of the inheritance hierarchy for a framework and guidelines when to use multiple levels of inheritance or join them in a single class?

Some references to established practices/examples that worked well in the Java world would be nice in the answers as this is from the perspective of the community and frameworks surrounding Java.

Comment: As shallow as possible, as deep as necessary

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You may be looking for a nice rule like "not more then 5 levels of inheritance" but I really doubt that there is such a rule. Objects usually model real world entities and the community of all those entities never agreed on a rule (as far as I know)...

One "best practice" is definitly: **favor composition over inheritance**. Following this guideline: define one interface and implementations with no further superclasses. All common fields and methods come with behaviour and [strategies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

On the other hand, we sometime model real world entities or structurs that already come with a deep hierarchy of entities. *Classification of animals* is one example or *[algebraic structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_algebraic_structures)*. A framework to model such existing structures would require a deep class hierarchy because it should follow the real world just to be understandable.

Comment: Of course, there are problems with animal classification as an inheritance structure.

Comment: I hate to see this *favor composition over inheritance* everywhere, outta context. You use composition where it matters and inheritance where it matters. The real rule should be *do not use inheritance as a code sharing mechanism.*

Comment: If at least one of the methods in the Superclass doesn't make sense to the subclass. You should replace inheritance for composition. For instance think of Stack Class inheriting from List Class. Even if they have similar operations and the list can be used as storage for the stack, several methods from List class don't make sense for stack class and would be present in the stack public interface in the case of inheritance which would be really awkward. Favor composition over inheritance in this case will be beneficial, at least you'll get rid of that smell.

Answer (score 6):

I think, from a maintenance point of view, as shallow an inheritance hierarchy as you can manage is the way to go.  Tracing bugs down through multiple hierarchical levels, and then having to figure out at which level they should then be fixed can be a tricky one.

Comment: I would argue the exact opposite way: By collapsing the classes into fewer, larger, classes, you make debugging harder.

Comment: @aioobe - This is true, but it is also possible to go too far and split things up too far, where composition would be favourable, rather than inheritance.  I've working on some complex hierarchies where this has happened...

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion each derived class is "a class of it's own", and the clients of this class, including subclasses) should in general not bother, or be interested in, how many classes there are between this class and the `Object` class.

Thus, my answer would be: No, let the hierarchy be as deep as it needs to be, as long as it makes sense / seems logical. Don't let the hierarchy depth influence the decision of whether or not to collapse two classes.  Since each subclass is a refinement of it's base class, my experience says that it seldom makes sense to have depths of more than 5 or 6 classes.

---

Just to be clear: As others have pointed out, you should favour composition over inheritance. To me however, that seems to answer a slightly different question though.

---

According to [this article](http://www.javaspecialists.co.za/archive/Issue121.html), the maximum depth in the standard Java API is 9.

Comment: This is simply wrong. Inheritance is a well know complexity factor.

Comment: Are you saying that by collapsing classes you get a less complex program?

Comment: Any code complexity metrics has a factor for class inheritance depth. According to MS MSDN the deeper the hierarchy the more difficult it might be to understand where particular methods and fields are defined or/and redefined

Comment: @Reza Any concept can be brought to extremes, we don't need MSDN to tell us that. That's why **aioobe** says *as long as it makes sense / seems logical*.

Comment: @Reza Also, if you're stressing technical difficulties with maintenance, any decent IDE will show you subclasses where method is redefined.

Comment: @aioobe, can you post a link to the article that says the maximum depth in the JDK is 9?  Was it in a now-deleted comment?

Comment: @Nikita IDE capability is irrelevant to code complexity. We don't measure code complexity based on an IDE capabilities and we don't design systems taking an IDE as a architectural consideration

Comment: @Reza What is relevant, then? You didn't do a very good job of conveying the cause of your disapproval, so I had to guess.

Answer (score 6):

From what I've seen (note: this isn't an official opinion, just my observations), 3-4 is a reasonable maximum.

Also, remember one important part from Effective Java:

> Favor composition over inheritance

Answer (score 2):

There is no best practices regarding maximum depth of inheritance. Instead of looking it in volume, this is the rule of thumb when it comes to inheritance in java (and any OO language for that matter).

1_ Before implementing inheritance check if "is a" relationship is true. Charger is a car. (so inheritance is fine). If you do this, then you will not end up with huge inheritance tree anyway. ( Wheel is not a car, so inheritance here is wrong)

2_ If "is a" relationship fails or you have ambiguity, then probable inheritance is not the way. You need to identify commonality among your classes and use composition.(refactoring common code to a new class).

3_ if you want to establish a type hierrarchy, then you should go with Interface inheritance (Type) not class level inheritance. (May be some of these statements need more explanation, but for that you probably need to pick up some book.)

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to best practices, performance(memory usage) also should be considered.

It will use more memory when you have deep hierarchy of classes (non-abstract). Like creating a new object of last child of 3 level inheritance will use LESS MEMORY than that of 9 level inheritance.
Based on nature of application this point could be considered, in addition to other posts.

Comment: Could the same not be said of Object Oriented vs procedural coding as well?

Answer (score 0):

You should think first about the clarity of the code you are writing.  Will having more level of depth make the code easier to read and maintain or will it make it harder.  Alot depending on the problem you are trying to solve.

As other posters suggest, you can make the depth either too shallow or too deep.  This is a goldilocks problem IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

The best is that each class takes care of a bunch of similar things.
Each method inside this class takes care of one action/behaviour.

Look at this refcard from DZone:
http://refcardz.dzone.com/assets/download/refcard/54c22c8b0a53591ea9e0504fdfd4bada/rc130-010d-designing-quality_0.pdf

Comment: A *bunch* of similar things? You don't like the Single Responsibility Principle?

Answer (score 0):

General rule is the deeper the hierarchy the more difficult it might be to understand where particular methods and fields are defined or/and redefined.

But beside the inheritance there are other factors that you need to be careful to keep your code complexity manageable.

The best approach is to use a code metrics tool and try to balance between different factors(lines of code, class decoupling and ...)